# Python: groupby and aggregate > adding to orginal df

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, aggregate

I have a data frame, with a categorical variable where the group sizes vary. 
Within every group of the categorical variable, I want to assign a random number between 1 and 10. I create as many random numbers between 1 and 10 as entries in a specific group.
To assign a random number I made a simple function called `createrandomnum`.

Then I used this line of code:

```
grouped_vales = data.groupby("categories").categories.agg(newnumber = createrandomnum)
```

Then the output is a data frame, where every row represents a category. The column named 'newnumber' contains lists with numbers between 1 and 10. The length of the list corresponds to the group sizes in the original data frame.

I would like to add these numbers to my original data frame. Which number is allocated to which entry is not that important, as long as the category is the same.

I figured I probably have to sort my original data frame;

```
data.sort_values("categories")
```

But then...

Anyone that could help me? Thanks in advance!

P.S. I just started learning Python, so maybe the code I provided here is not the most efficient. Tips are welcome of course :)

Comment: How looks function `createrandomnum` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) function for return new column (Series) with same size like original `DataFrame`:

```
data['new'] = data.groupby("categories").categories.transform(createrandomnum)
```

Comment: This works indeed, thanks a lot! I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

A method to add random number added:

```
import random    
data['new'] = data.groupby('categories')['categories'].transform(lambda group: random.randint(1,10))
```